# How to change the row Selector in GridView in Win C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have windows application in C#.Net2010.. i have added griview with some Comobobox and CheckBox columns..

I have set some rows Readonly in GridView for some data related issue..

now when event user select some value from combobox column and press enter and if next row is readonly i want to set rowSelector to row which is not readonly

I have written following Code :

```
 for (int i = gridAttendanceEntry.CurrentRow.Index + 1; i < gridAttendanceEntry.Rows.Count; i++)
             {
                 if (!gridAttendanceEntry.Rows[i].ReadOnly)
                 {
                     gridAttendanceEntry.Rows[i].Selected = true;
                     this.gridAttendanceEntry.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = i;
                     break;
                 }
                 if (i == gridAttendanceEntry.Rows.Count - 1)
                     i = 0;
             }
```

how can i change row selector programatically?

Answer (score 1):

1. get the selected / focused row index
2. temporarily save it to an integer variable and do + 1
3. check if the row with the new index is readonly. not? select it, else add 1 and do step 3 again

Comment: i have done exactly like you have specified : but and i have write Code: GridView.rows[i].selected = true; but still RowSelector still goes to next row which is readonly :

Comment: in which event to your write this code? in the selection changed or changing event? it might be that another event overrides this code

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!gridAttendanceEntry.Rows[i].ReadOnly) 
{ 
     gridAttendanceEntry.Rows[i].Selected = true; 
     this.gridAttendanceEntry.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = i; 
     break; 
}
else
{
     gridAttendanceEntry.Rows[i].Selected = false;
}
```

You need this else statement.  I do believe the default behavior of the control is to select the next row after you make a change in a combobox.  In your case, when that row is readonly, you need to make sure this has not happened by deselecting it manually.